Removing substring from postgreSQL Table column
In one of the postgreSQL table I have to remove these substring from below datacolumn
-637982129758340815 & -637982129753090712
Removing text starting from - and ending with ;.
There would be multiple presence of such combination in one column
DataColumn = "126758:3#1;95#0:#144:12-637982129758340815;145:2-637982129753090712",
Looking for a postgreSQL Script
Tried SubString & Remove but that needs exact value, here I am looking for a removal of text between "-" & ";"

regex_replace(column, '-\d{18};', '-;', 'g') I'm not clear which characters you want to keep as delimiters.
